# What is the difference between get() and valueChanges() in Angular Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says I would like to ask what is the difference (if there is any) between get() and valueChanges() when performing a query in Angular Firestore.

Are there also any advantages/disadvantages between the two maybe regarding the reads/costs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main difference between `valueChanges` and `get()`, is that with `get()`, you get the data only **once**, whereas `valueChanges` (and `snapshotChanges`) is automatically fired whenever something changes in the database linked to that document/collection that you are listening to.

The latter is the beauty of firebase realtime database, since you don't need to poll or anything else to get the latest data, firebase takes care of all of that!

In my opinion `get()` is useful to use when you for example update a document in a collection, and then instantly want to do something with that document after the update, and only fetch that once, like:

```ts
const docRef= this.afs.collection(colId).doc(docId).set(...)

docRef.get().pipe(
  map(doc => doc.data())
)
.subscribe(data => {
   // do stuff with document
})
```

Of course you could call the document with for example `valueChanges` and attach a `pipe(take(1))`, but `get()` is pretty handy in this case.

Comment: I don't think ```get()``` call will only retrieve data once. Its also an observable and it will trigger whenever a document data changes. Actual difference is that ```valueChanges()``` can be used with ```@angular/fire``` library whereas ```get()``` call was initiated for plain vanilla js

Answer (score 10):

`valueChanges()` is used in the library angularfire2. According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md):

> Returns an Observable of document data. All Snapshot metadata is stripped. This method provides only the data.

If you are doing an angular project, then you can use the library `angularfire2` which contains the method `valueChanges()`

---

[`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) is also used to retrieve the contents of a single document.