# firestore valueChanges() is not updating userdata instantly

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using Angular and cloud firestore for backend. I have a user profile, a logged in user and other users with follow or unfollow action button, based on the logged in user's current following list. I want the button text and the list of followers and following to get updated in the front end as soon as the click event is successfully completed. But, I am able to see the updated values only after there is a change in route, or I click the button twice.

Is there any way that, as soon as follow or unfollow is successful, data of loggedUser and selectedUser gets updated and the same updated data is reflected in my component.

userDetails.component.ts

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedUser = this.userService.getLoggedUserData();

    //--------Get displayed user data
    this.userService.SelectedUserChanged.pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(
      (user:User)=>{
        this.user=user;
        if(this.user){
          this.btnToDisplay(); //.....To show follow or unfollow depending on logged user's data
        }}
      );
  }
```

I have a UserService, where I have subscribed to logged user's valueChanges()

```
    fetchLoggedUser(uid: string) {   //Subscribed in the appcomponent using authenticated user's id.
    return this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        tap((user: User) => {
          this.loggeduser = user;
          this.loggeduser.id = user.userid;
          this.fetchAllUsers();
        })
      );
    }
      
    fetchAllUsers() {
        this.userSubs.push(
          this.db
            .collection('Users')
            .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
            .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
              this.allUsers = users;
              this.usersChanged.next([...this.allUsers]);
            })
        );
      }


    selectUser(uid: string) {
        this.selectedUser = this.allUsers.find((user) => user.id === uid);
        this.SelectedUserChanged.next({ ...this.selectedUser });
      }

    getLoggedUserData() {
        return ({...this.loggeduser});
      }

    followUser(uid: string, email: string) {
        this.db.collection('Users').doc(this.loggeduser.userid)
          .update({
            following: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
              uid: uid,
              email: email,
            }),
          });
    
        this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid)
          .update({
            followers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
              uid: this.loggeduser.userid,
              email: this.loggeduser.email,
            }),
          });
      }
```

Comment: In order to [listen to the changes that take place in your document], you need to use the `onSnapshot()` method. You may use it to listen to changes made in one doc or even listen all docs under a collection. Please check [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi @tzovourn I went through the documentation, but since I am new to Angular and firebase;I can't understand where exactly do I need to make the changes. The docs says to use `onSnapshot()` in place of `get()`; but I have not used `get()` method in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154310/what-is-the-difference-between-get-and-valuechanges-in-angular-firestore-que), `valueChanges()` and `onSnapshot()` automatically return the changes taking place to the document or collection that they are listening to. `get()` is used to get the data only once.

To achieve what you would like to, you'll need to follow the instructions on
[Get real time updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Based on this documentation, I have tested this code sample and when I am updating a value in the database the new document with the updated data are returned.

```
async function monitorUser(uid){

    const doc = db.collection('users').doc(uid);

    const observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
        console.log(`Received doc snapshot:`, docSnapshot.data());
    }, err => {
        console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    });
    
}
```

Then you can update the public variable that corresponds to your user's data with the new values and the view should be updated.