# How to map over an observed array to combine multiple obervables latest values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am piping into an observable, that streams an array of let's say food. I need to get the latest cook, the latest kitchen, and the latest knife used to prepare each of these food items. These three values are all values got by an observable like getCookById(food.cook.id).
How could i map it so:

- I'm waiting for the array of food
- When i receive it, I map on every food item to:

  - get latest cook, kitchen and knife that are all from Observables (combineLatest?)
  - combine all of that on an object like

```js
{
   foodItem,
   cook,
   kitchen,
   knife
}
```

- return the array of all these transformed items

Currently, I get an array of empty items doing it like so :

```js
    const foodObservable = new Subject();
    
    foodObservable.pipe(
      map(foodItems => {
        return foodItems.map((foodItem: any)=>{
          const cookObservable = new Subject();
          const kitchenObservable = new Subject();
          const knifeObservable = new Subject();

          combineLatest(cookObservable, kitchenObservable, knifeObservable).subscribe(([cook, kitchen, knife]) => {
            return {
              foodItem,
              cook,
              kitchen,
              knife
            };
          });
        })
      })
    ).subscribe(foodPreparationArray=>{
      console.log(foodPreparationArray) // array of empty values :(
    })
```

Comment: To get latest cook, kitchen and knife are u calling any HTTP service?

Comment: @prathameshk73 I kind of do, at least it's kind of the same thing: i'm currently migrating from firebase, so these observables are Angularfire's `db.collection('cook').doc(foodItem.cookId).valueChanges()`, which returns an observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your condition and your comment, I'd suggest the following changes

1. You'd need to use a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. `map` operator is used to transform the emitted data.
2. Using Firebase `get()` instead of `valueChanges()` would be a better fit. I assume you need the value at the moment and do not need to observe any changes to the property. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155188/6513921) for more info.
3. Using `get()` instead of `valueChanges()` provides us with us observables that completes instead of streaming. So you could replace the `combineLatest` with `forkJoin`.
4. You'd need two `forkJoin`s. First `forkJoin` is to trigger requests for each element of the `foodItems` array and second `forkJoin` is to trigger requests for `cook`, `knife`, and `kitchen` simultaneously.
5. Finally you could use the `map` operator to combining everything.

Try the following

```js
foodObservable.pipe(
  switchMap((foodItems: any) =>                                            // <-- RxJS `switchMap` operator
    forkJoin(
      foodItems.map((foodItem: any) =>                                     // <-- JS `Array#map` function
        forkJoin({
          cook: db.collection('cook').doc(foodItem.cookId).get(),
          kitchen: db.collection('kitchen').doc(foodItem.kitchenId).get(),
          knife: db.collection('knife').doc(foodItem.knifeId).get()
        }).pipe(
          map(({cook, kitchen, knife}) => ({                               // <-- RxJS `map` operator
            ...foodItem,                                                   // <-- spread operator
            cook: cook,
            kitchen: kitchen,
            knife: knife
          )})
        )
      )
    )
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (foodPreparationArray: any) => {
    console.log(foodPreparationArray);
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```