# How do you await data from firebase?

Tags: typescript, angularfire2

I want to wait for data to return before calling my next function in angularfire.

Here is my current code... I want to replace set timeout... I know this isnt the best way of doing this.

```
  function(){
    this.db.collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc').valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
      this.myData = res
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myFunction(this.myData)
    }, 1500);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to `await` here.

`await` is a tool to manage Promises. Promises, in turn, are a tool to wait for something to happen once.

`valueChanges` happen **every time** the value changes, not just once.

If you were to wrap this in a promise, then it would work the first time the value changed, but then fail the next time it did.

---

You should either [use `get` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155188/19068) or do the work in the subscription function so it gets done each time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
const myData = (
  await this.db.collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc').get().toPromise()
).data()
```